# How to maximize $p_1p_2$ subject to constraints?

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming, non-convex-optimization

> Given $x_2 \geq x_1 \geq 0$, solve the following optimization problem in $p_1$ and $p_2$.
>
> $$\max p_1p_2$$
>
> subject to:
>
> $$p_1 x_1 + p_2 (x_2 - x_1) = 1 $$
> $$0\leq p_2 \leq p_1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had planned to answer [your deleted question on maximum likelihood](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3167408/maximum-likelihood-of-non-increasing-pdfs).  I think the answer here depends on whether $x_2 \gt 2x_1$ or $x_2 \lt 2x_1$:

- If $x_2 \ge 2x_1$, I think the product is maximised when $p_1=\frac1{2x_1}$ and $p_2=\frac1{2(x_2-x_1)}$ which makes the product $p_1p_2 = \frac1{4x_1(x_2-x_1)}$, essentially for the reason Maria Mazur gives in her answer
- If $2x_1 \ge x_2 \ge x_1$, I think the product is maximised when $p_1=p_2=\frac1{x_2}$  which makes the product $p_1p_2 = \frac1{x_2^2}$

Note that, as you might expect, these are equal when $x_2 = 2x_1$ since they are then both $\frac1{4x_1^2} = \frac1{x_2^2}$

Comment: This is very interesting, thank you! (The MLE question seemed to be causing some controversy so I restated it in this simpler way.)  I guess there is still a problem when $x_2 \geq 2x_1$ but $\frac{1}{2x_1} > 1$. Maybe we need to assume all the $x_i$ are integers greater than $1$?  But I am not sure why we should need that.

Comment: @Arthur Not a problem - probability densities can be greater than $1$ on a small support, such as a uniform distribution on $[0,\frac12]$ which has density of $2$.  It is probabilities, i.e. the integral of densities, which cannot exceed $1$

Comment: A very good point (slaps forehead).

Answer (score 2):

Let $p_2=t$, $x_2-x_1=y\geq 0$ and $x_1=x$, then $$p_1 = {1-ty\over x}$$ so $$p_1p_2 = t{1-ty\over x} = -{y\over x}t^2+{1\over x}t$$

If $y\neq 0$ then this quadratic equation achieves maximum at $t= {1\over 2y}$ and that maximum is $${1\over 4xy}={1\over 4x_1(x_2-x_1)}$$

If $y=0$ we get  $$p_1p_2 = {1\over x}t\leq {1\over x}$$

so in this case maximum is $1/x$

Comment: What happens if $x_2  = x_1$? In that case $p_1 = 1/x_1$ and $p_1 = p_2$ I guess.

Comment: I don't  think this satisfies the constraint that $p_2 \leq p_1$. Take $x_1 = 3$ and $x_2 = 4$ for example.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the lagrangian with the help of $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2$ as slack variables,

$$
L(p,\lambda,\epsilon) = p_1p_2+\lambda_1(p_1 x_1+p_2(x_2-x_1)-1)+\lambda_2(p_2-\epsilon_1^2)+\lambda_3(p_1-p_2-\epsilon_2^2)
$$

and solving the stationary conditions

$$
\nabla L = 0
$$

we get.

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
p_1 & p_2 & \lambda_1 & \lambda_2 & \lambda_3 & \epsilon_1^2 & \epsilon_2^2 & p_1 p_2\\
 \frac{1}{x_1} & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{x_1} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{x_1} & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{x_1} & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{x_1} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{x_1} & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{2 x_1} & \frac{1}{2 \left(x_2-x_1\right)} & \frac{1}{2 x_1^2-2 x_1 x_2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \left(x_2-x_1\right)} & \frac{1}{2}
   \left(\frac{1}{x_1-x_2}+\frac{1}{x_1}\right) & \frac 14\frac{1}{ x_1 x_2-x_1^2} \\
 \frac{1}{2 x_1} & \frac{1}{2 \left(x_2-x_1\right)} & \frac{1}{2 x_1^2-2 x_1 x_2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \left(x_2-x_1\right)} & \frac{1}{2}
   \left(\frac{1}{x_1-x_2}+\frac{1}{x_1}\right) & \frac 14\frac{1}{ x_1 x_2-x_1^2}\\
 \frac{1}{2 x_1} & \frac{1}{2 \left(x_2-x_1\right)} & \frac{1}{2 x_1^2-2 x_1 x_2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \left(x_2-x_1\right)} & \frac{1}{2}
   \left(\frac{1}{x_1-x_2}+\frac{1}{x_1}\right) & \frac 14\frac{1}{ x_1 x_2-x_1^2} \\
 \frac{1}{2 x_1} & \frac{1}{2 \left(x_2-x_1\right)} & \frac{1}{2 x_1^2-2 x_1 x_2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \left(x_2-x_1\right)} & \frac{1}{2}
   \left(\frac{1}{x_1-x_2}+\frac{1}{x_1}\right) & \frac 14\frac{1}{ x_1 x_2-x_1^2} \\
 \frac{1}{x_2} & \frac{1}{x_2} & -\frac{2}{x_2^2} & 0 & \frac{2 x_1-x_2}{x_2^2} & \frac{1}{x_2} & 0 & \frac{1}{x_2^2} \\
 \frac{1}{x_2} & \frac{1}{x_2} & -\frac{2}{x_2^2} & 0 & \frac{2 x_1-x_2}{x_2^2} & \frac{1}{x_2} & 0 & \frac{1}{x_2^2} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

The number of solutions is due to the introduction of $\epsilon_i^2$. To be feasible one solution should have $\epsilon_i^2\ge 0$. Note also that the restriction is active when the corresponding $\epsilon_i$ is null.

Comment: I am not sure how to interpret your answer. Does it, for example, confirm the answer of Henry?  Also, where are the constraints on the order of the $p_i$ variables represented?

Comment: @Arthur $p_1-\epsilon_1^2 = 0$ is equivalent to $p_1 \ge 0$ and $p_2-p_1-\epsilon_2^2=0$ is equivalent to $p_2\ge p_1$. The consideration of $\frac{1}{4x_1(x_2-x_1}$ as an extremal depends on $x_1^2-x_1x_2 \ge 0$ which is false so the only extremal to consider is $\frac{1}{x_2^2}$

Comment: as was already suggested.

Comment: Just to clarify, the other answer splits into two cases. One where $2x_1 \ge x_2 \ge x_1$ and one where $x_2 \ge 2x_1$ in which case $p_1p_2 = \frac1{4x_1(x_2-x_1)}$.  Is this the same as in your answer? (Sorry if I am missing something really simple.)

Comment: @Arthur Note the value of $\epsilon_2$ In the denominator appears a radical for $x_1^2-x_1x_2$ here as long as $x_2 \ge x_1$ we have $x_1^2-x_1x_2\le 0$ so the only feasible answer is $\frac{1}{x_2^2}$ as the maximum.

Comment: That doesn't seem right however.  Take $x_2 = 4$ and $x_1=1$. We can achieve value of $1/12$ which is larger than $1/16$ by setting $p_1 = 1/2$ and $p_2 = 1/6$.

Comment: @Arthur You are right. I had changed $p_1$ to $p_2$ in the formulation. Now it is correct and the results agree with your hypothesis.

Comment: Thank you. Is the $x_2 \geq 2x_1$ condition  spelled out somewhere  in your answer? I don't fully understand how to read it.  What I mean is, how can you tell from your answer under what conditions you will get each maximum for $p_1p_2$?

Comment: @Arthur. This condition appears as $2\epsilon_i^2 = \frac{1}{x_1-x_2}+\frac{1}{x_1} \ge 0$ which results in $\frac{x_2-2x_1}{(x_2-x_1)x_1} \ge 0\Rightarrow  x_2 \ge 2 x_1$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Substitute from the constraint in the object function (considering $0\le p_1\le p_2\le1$) and differentiate with respect to the remaining variable. Then compare it with the value of the object function in the limit points.