# Maximise $p_1p_2p_3p_4p_5$ subject to constraints

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

> Given $x_5 \geq x_4 \geq x_3 \geq x_2 \geq x_1 \geq 0$, solve the following optimization problem in $p_1, p_2,\dots, p_5$.
>
> $$\max p_1p_2p_3p_4p_5$$
>
> subject to:
>
> $$p_1 x_1 + p_2 (x_2 - x_1) + p_3(x_3-x_2) + p_4(x_4-x_3)+p_5(x_5-x_4) = 1 $$
> $$0\leq p_5 \leq p_4 \leq p_3 \leq p_2 \leq p_1$$

Is there a closed form solution to this problem?  I am not sure how to go about approaching it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of the slack variables $\epsilon_i$ and calling

$$
L(p,\mu,\epsilon,\lambda)= p_1 p_2 p_3 p_4 p_5+\mu _5 \left(p_1-p_2-\epsilon _5^2\right)+\mu _4 \left(p_2-p_3-\epsilon _4^2\right)+\mu _3 \left(p_3-p_4-\epsilon _3^2\right)+\mu _2
   \left(p_4-p_5-\epsilon _2^2\right)+\mu _1 \left(p_5-\epsilon _1^2\right)+\lambda  \left(p_1 x_1+p_2 \left(x_2-x_1\right)+p_3
   \left(x_3-x_2\right)+p_4 \left(x_4-x_3\right)+p_5 \left(x_5-x_4\right)-1\right)
$$

and solving the sationary conditions

$$
\nabla L = 0
$$

we obtain a set of solutions jointly with a set of conditions $\epsilon_i^2\ge 0$ to qualify those solutions. To be feasible the solution requires that $\epsilon_i^2\ge 0$ Also when $\epsilon_i^2 = 0$ it means that the corresponding restriction is active.

Due to the length of the symbolic response, we leave a script in MATHEMATICA that summarizes the results. There are sixteen non trivial solutions in **res0** with structure $\{p_i,\epsilon_i^2,p_1p_2p_3p_4p_5\}$

```
n = 5;
X = Table[Subscript[x, k], {k, 1, n}];
P = Table[Subscript[p, k], {k, 1, n}];
EE = Table[Subscript[epsilon, k], {k, 1, n}];
M = Table[Subscript[mu, k], {k, 1, n}];
vars = Join[Join[Join[P, M], EE], {lambda}]
prod = Product[P[[k]], {k, 1, n}]
L = prod
L += lambda (Sum[P[[k]] (X[[k]] - X[[k - 1]]), {k, 2, n}] + P[[1]] X[[1]] - 1)
L += Sum[M[[k]] (P[[n - k + 1]] - P[[n - k + 2]] + EE[[k]]^2), {k, 2, n}] + M[[1]] (P[[n]] - EE[[1]]^2)
grad = Grad[L, vars]
equs = Thread[grad == 0];
E2 = EE^2;
results = Join[Join[P, E2], {prod}];
sols = Quiet[Solve[equs, vars]];
results0 = results /. sols // FullSimplify;
For[i = 1; res = {}, i <= Length[results0], i++,
  If[NumberQ[results0[[i]][[2 n + 1]]] == False, AppendTo[res,results0[[i]]]]
]
res0 = Union[res];
res0 // MatrixForm
```

Results for $n = 3$

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
p_1&p_2&p_3&\epsilon_1^2&\epsilon_2^2&\epsilon_3^2&p_1p_2p_3\\
 \frac{1}{3 x_1} & \frac{1}{3 \left(x_2-x_1\right)} & \frac{1}{3 \left(x_3-x_2\right)} & \frac{1}{3 \left(x_3-x_2\right)} & \frac{1}{3 x_2-3
   x_3}+\frac{1}{3 \left(x_2-x_1\right)} & \frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{1}{x_1-x_2}+\frac{1}{x_1}\right) & \frac{1}{27 \left(x_1^2-x_1 x_2\right)
   \left(x_2-x_3\right)} \\
 \frac{1}{3 x_1} & \frac{2}{3 \left(x_3-x_1\right)} & \frac{2}{3 \left(x_3-x_1\right)} & \frac{2}{3 \left(x_3-x_1\right)} & 0 & \frac{1}{3}
   \left(\frac{2}{x_1-x_3}+\frac{1}{x_1}\right) & \frac{4}{27 x_1 \left(x_1-x_3\right){}^2} \\
 \frac{2}{3 x_2} & \frac{2}{3 x_2} & \frac{1}{3 \left(x_3-x_2\right)} & \frac{1}{3 \left(x_3-x_2\right)} & \frac{1}{3 x_2-3 x_3}+\frac{2}{3
   x_2} & 0 & \frac{4}{27 x_2^2 \left(x_3-x_2\right)} \\
 \frac{1}{x_3} & \frac{1}{x_3} & \frac{1}{x_3} & \frac{1}{x_3} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{x_3^3} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Results for $n = 4$

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
p_1 & p_2 & p_3 & p_4 & \epsilon_1^2&\epsilon_2^2&\epsilon_3^2&\epsilon_4^2&p_1p_2p_3p_4\\
\frac{1}{4 x_1} & \frac{1}{4 \left(x_2-x_1\right)} & \frac{1}{4 \left(x_3-x_2\right)} & \frac{1}{4 \left(x_4-x_3\right)} & \frac{1}{4
   \left(x_4-x_3\right)} & \frac{1}{4 x_3-4 x_4}+\frac{1}{4 \left(x_3-x_2\right)} & \frac{1}{4 x_2-4 x_3}+\frac{1}{4 \left(x_2-x_1\right)} &
   \frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{1}{x_1-x_2}+\frac{1}{x_1}\right) & -\frac{1}{256 \left(x_1^2-x_1 x_2\right) \left(x_2-x_3\right)
   \left(x_3-x_4\right)} \\
 \frac{1}{4 x_1} & \frac{1}{4 \left(x_2-x_1\right)} & \frac{1}{2 \left(x_4-x_2\right)} & \frac{1}{2 \left(x_4-x_2\right)} & \frac{1}{2
   \left(x_4-x_2\right)} & 0 & \frac{1}{2 x_2-2 x_4}+\frac{1}{4 \left(x_2-x_1\right)} & \frac{1}{4}
   \left(\frac{1}{x_1-x_2}+\frac{1}{x_1}\right) & -\frac{1}{64 x_1 \left(x_1-x_2\right) \left(x_2-x_4\right){}^2} \\
 \frac{1}{4 x_1} & \frac{1}{2 \left(x_3-x_1\right)} & \frac{1}{2 \left(x_3-x_1\right)} & \frac{1}{4 \left(x_4-x_3\right)} & \frac{1}{4
   \left(x_4-x_3\right)} & \frac{1}{4 x_3-4 x_4}+\frac{1}{2 \left(x_3-x_1\right)} & 0 & \frac{1}{4}
   \left(\frac{2}{x_1-x_3}+\frac{1}{x_1}\right) & \frac{1}{64 x_1 \left(x_1-x_3\right){}^2 \left(x_4-x_3\right)} \\
 \frac{1}{4 x_1} & \frac{3}{4 \left(x_4-x_1\right)} & \frac{3}{4 \left(x_4-x_1\right)} & \frac{3}{4 \left(x_4-x_1\right)} & \frac{3}{4
   \left(x_4-x_1\right)} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{3}{x_1-x_4}+\frac{1}{x_1}\right) & \frac{27}{256 x_1 \left(x_4-x_1\right){}^3} \\
 \frac{1}{2 x_2} & \frac{1}{2 x_2} & \frac{1}{4 \left(x_3-x_2\right)} & \frac{1}{4 \left(x_4-x_3\right)} & \frac{1}{4 \left(x_4-x_3\right)} &
   \frac{1}{4 x_3-4 x_4}+\frac{1}{4 \left(x_3-x_2\right)} & \frac{1}{4 x_2-4 x_3}+\frac{1}{2 x_2} & 0 & \frac{1}{64 x_2^2
   \left(x_2-x_3\right) \left(x_3-x_4\right)} \\
 \frac{1}{2 x_2} & \frac{1}{2 x_2} & \frac{1}{2 \left(x_4-x_2\right)} & \frac{1}{2 \left(x_4-x_2\right)} & \frac{1}{2 \left(x_4-x_2\right)} &
   0 & \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{x_2-x_4}+\frac{1}{x_2}\right) & 0 & \frac{1}{16 x_2^2 \left(x_2-x_4\right){}^2} \\
 \frac{3}{4 x_3} & \frac{3}{4 x_3} & \frac{3}{4 x_3} & \frac{1}{4 \left(x_4-x_3\right)} & \frac{1}{4 \left(x_4-x_3\right)} & \frac{1}{4 x_3-4
   x_4}+\frac{3}{4 x_3} & 0 & 0 & \frac{27}{256 x_3^3 \left(x_4-x_3\right)} \\
 \frac{1}{x_4} & \frac{1}{x_4} & \frac{1}{x_4} & \frac{1}{x_4} & \frac{1}{x_4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{x_4^4} \\\end{array}
\right]
$$

and for $n = 5$

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
p_1&p_2&p_3&p_4&p_5&\epsilon_1^2&\epsilon_2^2&\epsilon_3^2&\epsilon_4^2&\epsilon_5^2&p_1p_2p_3p_4p_5\\
 \frac{1}{5 x_1} & -\frac{1}{5 \left(x_1-x_2\right)} & -\frac{1}{5 \left(x_2-x_3\right)} & -\frac{1}{5 \left(x_3-x_4\right)} & -\frac{1}{5
   \left(x_4-x_5\right)} & -\frac{1}{5 \left(x_4-x_5\right)} & \frac{x_3-2 x_4+x_5}{5 \left(x_3-x_4\right) \left(x_4-x_5\right)} &
   \frac{x_2-2 x_3+x_4}{5 \left(x_2-x_3\right) \left(x_3-x_4\right)} & \frac{x_1-2 x_2+x_3}{5 \left(x_1-x_2\right) \left(x_2-x_3\right)} &
   \frac{2 x_1-x_2}{5 x_1 \left(x_1-x_2\right)} & \frac{1}{3125 x_1 \left(x_1-x_2\right) \left(x_2-x_3\right) \left(x_3-x_4\right)
   \left(x_4-x_5\right)} \\
 \frac{1}{5 x_1} & -\frac{1}{5 \left(x_1-x_2\right)} & -\frac{1}{5 \left(x_2-x_3\right)} & -\frac{2}{5 \left(x_3-x_5\right)} & -\frac{2}{5
   \left(x_3-x_5\right)} & -\frac{2}{5 \left(x_3-x_5\right)} & 0 & \frac{2 x_2-3 x_3+x_5}{5 \left(x_2-x_3\right) \left(x_3-x_5\right)} &
   \frac{x_1-2 x_2+x_3}{5 \left(x_1-x_2\right) \left(x_2-x_3\right)} & \frac{2 x_1-x_2}{5 x_1 \left(x_1-x_2\right)} & \frac{4}{3125 x_1
   \left(x_1-x_2\right) \left(x_2-x_3\right) \left(x_3-x_5\right){}^2} \\
 \frac{1}{5 x_1} & -\frac{1}{5 \left(x_1-x_2\right)} & -\frac{2}{5 \left(x_2-x_4\right)} & -\frac{2}{5 \left(x_2-x_4\right)} & -\frac{1}{5
   \left(x_4-x_5\right)} & -\frac{1}{5 \left(x_4-x_5\right)} & \frac{x_2-3 x_4+2 x_5}{5 \left(x_2-x_4\right) \left(x_4-x_5\right)} & 0 &
   \frac{2 x_1-3 x_2+x_4}{5 \left(x_1-x_2\right) \left(x_2-x_4\right)} & \frac{2 x_1-x_2}{5 x_1 \left(x_1-x_2\right)} & \frac{4}{3125 x_1
   \left(x_1-x_2\right) \left(x_2-x_4\right){}^2 \left(x_4-x_5\right)} \\
 \frac{1}{5 x_1} & -\frac{1}{5 \left(x_1-x_2\right)} & -\frac{3}{5 \left(x_2-x_5\right)} & -\frac{3}{5 \left(x_2-x_5\right)} & -\frac{3}{5
   \left(x_2-x_5\right)} & -\frac{3}{5 \left(x_2-x_5\right)} & 0 & 0 & \frac{3 x_1-4 x_2+x_5}{5 \left(x_1-x_2\right) \left(x_2-x_5\right)} &
   \frac{2 x_1-x_2}{5 x_1 \left(x_1-x_2\right)} & \frac{27}{3125 x_1 \left(x_1-x_2\right) \left(x_2-x_5\right){}^3} \\
 \frac{1}{5 x_1} & -\frac{2}{5 \left(x_1-x_3\right)} & -\frac{2}{5 \left(x_1-x_3\right)} & -\frac{1}{5 \left(x_3-x_4\right)} & -\frac{1}{5
   \left(x_4-x_5\right)} & -\frac{1}{5 \left(x_4-x_5\right)} & \frac{x_3-2 x_4+x_5}{5 \left(x_3-x_4\right) \left(x_4-x_5\right)} &
   \frac{x_1-3 x_3+2 x_4}{5 \left(x_1-x_3\right) \left(x_3-x_4\right)} & 0 & \frac{3 x_1-x_3}{5 x_1 \left(x_1-x_3\right)} & \frac{4}{3125 x_1
   \left(x_1-x_3\right){}^2 \left(x_3-x_4\right) \left(x_4-x_5\right)} \\
 \frac{1}{5 x_1} & -\frac{2}{5 \left(x_1-x_3\right)} & -\frac{2}{5 \left(x_1-x_3\right)} & -\frac{2}{5 \left(x_3-x_5\right)} & -\frac{2}{5
   \left(x_3-x_5\right)} & -\frac{2}{5 \left(x_3-x_5\right)} & 0 & \frac{2 \left(x_1-2 x_3+x_5\right)}{5 \left(x_1-x_3\right)
   \left(x_3-x_5\right)} & 0 & \frac{3 x_1-x_3}{5 x_1 \left(x_1-x_3\right)} & \frac{16}{3125 x_1 \left(x_1-x_3\right){}^2
   \left(x_3-x_5\right){}^2} \\
 \frac{1}{5 x_1} & -\frac{3}{5 \left(x_1-x_4\right)} & -\frac{3}{5 \left(x_1-x_4\right)} & -\frac{3}{5 \left(x_1-x_4\right)} & -\frac{1}{5
   \left(x_4-x_5\right)} & -\frac{1}{5 \left(x_4-x_5\right)} & \frac{x_1-4 x_4+3 x_5}{5 \left(x_1-x_4\right) \left(x_4-x_5\right)} & 0 & 0 &
   \frac{4 x_1-x_4}{5 x_1 \left(x_1-x_4\right)} & \frac{27}{3125 x_1 \left(x_1-x_4\right){}^3 \left(x_4-x_5\right)} \\
 \frac{1}{5 x_1} & -\frac{4}{5 \left(x_1-x_5\right)} & -\frac{4}{5 \left(x_1-x_5\right)} & -\frac{4}{5 \left(x_1-x_5\right)} & -\frac{4}{5
   \left(x_1-x_5\right)} & -\frac{4}{5 \left(x_1-x_5\right)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{5 x_1-x_5}{5 x_1 \left(x_1-x_5\right)} & \frac{256}{3125 x_1
   \left(x_1-x_5\right){}^4} \\
 \frac{2}{5 x_2} & \frac{2}{5 x_2} & -\frac{1}{5 \left(x_2-x_3\right)} & -\frac{1}{5 \left(x_3-x_4\right)} & -\frac{1}{5
   \left(x_4-x_5\right)} & -\frac{1}{5 \left(x_4-x_5\right)} & \frac{x_3-2 x_4+x_5}{5 \left(x_3-x_4\right) \left(x_4-x_5\right)} &
   \frac{x_2-2 x_3+x_4}{5 \left(x_2-x_3\right) \left(x_3-x_4\right)} & \frac{3 x_2-2 x_3}{5 x_2 \left(x_2-x_3\right)} & 0 & -\frac{4}{3125
   x_2^2 \left(x_2-x_3\right) \left(x_3-x_4\right) \left(x_4-x_5\right)} \\
 \frac{2}{5 x_2} & \frac{2}{5 x_2} & -\frac{1}{5 \left(x_2-x_3\right)} & -\frac{2}{5 \left(x_3-x_5\right)} & -\frac{2}{5
   \left(x_3-x_5\right)} & -\frac{2}{5 \left(x_3-x_5\right)} & 0 & \frac{2 x_2-3 x_3+x_5}{5 \left(x_2-x_3\right) \left(x_3-x_5\right)} &
   \frac{3 x_2-2 x_3}{5 x_2 \left(x_2-x_3\right)} & 0 & -\frac{16}{3125 x_2^2 \left(x_2-x_3\right) \left(x_3-x_5\right){}^2} \\
 \frac{2}{5 x_2} & \frac{2}{5 x_2} & -\frac{2}{5 \left(x_2-x_4\right)} & -\frac{2}{5 \left(x_2-x_4\right)} & -\frac{1}{5
   \left(x_4-x_5\right)} & -\frac{1}{5 \left(x_4-x_5\right)} & \frac{x_2-3 x_4+2 x_5}{5 \left(x_2-x_4\right) \left(x_4-x_5\right)} & 0 &
   \frac{2 \left(2 x_2-x_4\right)}{5 x_2 \left(x_2-x_4\right)} & 0 & -\frac{16}{3125 x_2^2 \left(x_2-x_4\right){}^2 \left(x_4-x_5\right)} \\
 \frac{2}{5 x_2} & \frac{2}{5 x_2} & -\frac{3}{5 \left(x_2-x_5\right)} & -\frac{3}{5 \left(x_2-x_5\right)} & -\frac{3}{5
   \left(x_2-x_5\right)} & -\frac{3}{5 \left(x_2-x_5\right)} & 0 & 0 & \frac{5 x_2-2 x_5}{5 x_2 \left(x_2-x_5\right)} & 0 & -\frac{108}{3125
   x_2^2 \left(x_2-x_5\right){}^3} \\
 \frac{3}{5 x_3} & \frac{3}{5 x_3} & \frac{3}{5 x_3} & -\frac{1}{5 \left(x_3-x_4\right)} & -\frac{1}{5 \left(x_4-x_5\right)} & -\frac{1}{5
   \left(x_4-x_5\right)} & \frac{x_3-2 x_4+x_5}{5 \left(x_3-x_4\right) \left(x_4-x_5\right)} & \frac{4 x_3-3 x_4}{5 x_3 \left(x_3-x_4\right)}
   & 0 & 0 & \frac{27}{3125 x_3^3 \left(x_3-x_4\right) \left(x_4-x_5\right)} \\
 \frac{3}{5 x_3} & \frac{3}{5 x_3} & \frac{3}{5 x_3} & -\frac{2}{5 \left(x_3-x_5\right)} & -\frac{2}{5 \left(x_3-x_5\right)} & -\frac{2}{5
   \left(x_3-x_5\right)} & 0 & \frac{5 x_3-3 x_5}{5 x_3 \left(x_3-x_5\right)} & 0 & 0 & \frac{108}{3125 x_3^3 \left(x_3-x_5\right){}^2} \\
 \frac{4}{5 x_4} & \frac{4}{5 x_4} & \frac{4}{5 x_4} & \frac{4}{5 x_4} & -\frac{1}{5 \left(x_4-x_5\right)} & -\frac{1}{5
   \left(x_4-x_5\right)} & \frac{5 x_4-4 x_5}{5 x_4 \left(x_4-x_5\right)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{256}{3125 x_4^4 \left(x_4-x_5\right)} \\
 \frac{1}{x_5} & \frac{1}{x_5} & \frac{1}{x_5} & \frac{1}{x_5} & \frac{1}{x_5} & \frac{1}{x_5} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{x_5^5} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Comment: Is there any way to summarize this at all for those of us without Mathematica? Perhaps give the results for $n=3$ or $n=4$? I’m curious to see the various cases.

Comment: Please—I should add!

Comment: It would be great if someone could translate this into an open source programming language. Maybe Python + sympy for example?

Comment: @DavidM. Added the results for $n = 3,4,5$

Comment: Thanks! If I'm interpreting the results correctly, the $n=5$ table doesn't include the case covered in my answer (_i.e._ that $p_i=1/x_5$ for all $i=1,\dots,5$). Am I missing something?

Comment: @DavidM. Thank goodness you are attentive and take account of the results. There was a changed index that invalidated the results. Now it is solved. I think so.

Comment: @DavidM. Now the script is more functional also.

Comment: The solution with all $p_i$ equal seems to be for the case $\frac{5}{x_5}\geq\max_{i=1,\dots,4}\big\{\frac{i}{x_i}\big\}.
$ according to the answer by David M. I may well be wrong but I don't see that in your answer.

Comment: @Anush It’s in the final row of the table

Comment: @DavidM. I see that all $p_i$ are equal for that row but how would you infer the case rule? I don't fully understand the table but how do you know when are in this case from the table?

Comment: @Anush I think those have to be worked out by hand (unless I'm mistaken).

Comment: @DavidM. I thought (naively) that you just set $\epsilon_1^2 \geq 0$ but in this case that gives you nothing. So I am lost :)

Comment: Thank you for this! What is the rule for how you extract the cases from one of your tables? If we take the $n=3$ table, how do we know when the answer will be $1/x_3^3$?

Answer (score 2):

Well you could try with Am-Gm inequality:

$$ 5\sqrt[5]{p_1p_2...p_5x_1(x_2-x_1)...(x_5-x_4)}\leq 1$$

So $$p_1p_2...p_5 \leq {1\over 5^5x_1(x_2-x_1)...(x_5-x_4)}$$

and this value is achivable if $$ p_1 ={1\over 5x_1}$$

$$ p_2 ={1\over 5(x_2-x_1)}$$
 $$ p_3 ={1\over 5(x_3-x_2)}$$
$$...$$

Comment: I am not sure this satisfies the ordering constraints on the $p_i$ does it?

Answer (score 1):

This answer addresses the case when
$$
\frac{5}{x_5}\geq\max_{i=1,\dots,4}\big\{\frac{i}{x_i}\big\}.
$$
In this case, the solution using the AM-GM inequality fails to satisfy the ordering constraint. There are still other cases to be considered, for example, $x=(1,\;3,\;4.75,\;8.75,\;13.75)$ which produces the solution $p_1=1/5$, $p_2=p_3=8/75$, $p_4=1/20$ and $p_5=1/25$ (computed this solution numerically).

---

While the other answers are clever, I don't believe that they respect the ordering constraint $0\leq{p_5}\leq\dots\leq{p_1}$. My proposed solution is found using the KKT conditions. (Note: I assume $x_i>0$ for all $i$--the case when $x_i=0$ should following from a similar technique to what I use below).

**Answer:** $p_1=p_2=p_3=p_4=p_5=1/x_5$.

**Solution:** By taking the logarithm of the objective function, the given optimization problem can be formulated as a convex optimization problem in standard form:
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\min & -\log(p_1)-\log(p_2)-\cdots-\log(p_5)\\
\text{s.t.} & p_1x_1+p_2(x_2-x_1)+p_3(x_3-x_2)+p_4(x_4-x_3)+p_5(x_5-x_4)-1=0\\
&p_2-p_1\leq0\\
&p_3-p_2\leq0\\
&p_4-p_3\leq0\\
&p_5-p_4\leq0\\
&\hspace{12pt}-p_5\leq0
\end{array}
$$
Associate the multiplier $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ with the equality constraint, and $\mu_i\geq0$ with the remaining constraints $i=1,\dots,5$. The stationarity conditions for this optimization problem are
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{p_1}&=\lambda{x_1}-\mu_1\\
\frac{1}{p_2}&=\lambda(x_2-x_1)+(\mu_1-\mu_2)\\
\frac{1}{p_3}&=\lambda(x_3-x_2)+(\mu_2-\mu_3)\\
\frac{1}{p_4}&=\lambda(x_4-x_3)+(\mu_3-\mu_4)\\
\frac{1}{p_5}&=\lambda(x_5-x_4)+(\mu_4-\mu_5)\\
\end{align*}
A solution to the above system is 
\begin{align*}
p_i&=\frac{1}{x_5}&&\text{for }i=1,\dots,5\\
\mu_i&=5x_i-i\cdot{x_5}&&\text{for }i=1,\dots,5\\
\lambda&=5
\end{align*}
It's easy to verify that the other KKT conditions are satisfied (complementary slackness, *etc*.), and to check that the problem satisfies the Slater condition. Hence, we conclude that the proposed point is indeed globally optimal for this problem.

Comment: This is intriguing if true.  However, is your answer compatible with https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3167600/387242 ?

Comment: @Arthur Actually yes I must have made an assumption somewhere--forgive me, I did this rather quickly. In the case when the $x$s are spaced appropriately, Maria Mazura's answer is correct. My answer must make an additional assumption--will look over soon, hopefully.

Comment: Thanks so much!  You are right of course that the other answers are ignoring the ordering constraint.

Comment: @Arthur Indeed I made a mistake when checking the complementary slackness conditions. My solution addresses a special case (analogous to the case when $2x_1>x_2$ in the linked answer). I think there are more cases that need to be considered here.

Answer (score 0):

Letting
$y_1 = x_1$
and
$y_i 
=x_i-x_{i-1}$ 
for $i>1$,
this is
$\sum_{i=1}^n p_iy_i
=1
$
with $n=5, y_i \ge 0$.

As Maria Mazur suggested,
using AM-GM gives
$\prod_{i=1}^n p_iy_i
\le (\frac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^n p_iy_i)^n
=\frac1{n^n}
$
with equality iff
$p_iy_i =\frac1{n}
$
or
$p_i = \frac1{ny_i}
$.

Note that there may be a problem
if some $y_i = 0$;
in this case,
$p_i$ can be any value.
Perhaps the conditions should be
$y_i > 0$.

(Added after a comment)

Regarding the requirement
that
$p_{i+1} \le p_i$:

This will hold if
$y_{i+1} \ge y_i$.

If not,
perhaps use the same idea
of defining
$q_i = p_i-p_{i+1}
$,
rewriting in terms of the $q_i$,
and requiring $q_i \ge 0$.

Comment: I think something has to happen to make sure the $p_i$ satisfy the order constraint.

Comment: You are right - I overlooked that. I'll add something about it.